# Broken GD Library Pngs In Firefox

Tags: php, gd

I've created my own custom Spider Chart generator using PHP and the GD Library. Basically, the user answers a series of questions, and a Spider Chart is generated based on the answers to the questions.

Overall, everything works great. The chart that's generated is mathematically accurate (though, the quiz needs to be reworded entirely), and it seems to work quickly enough. However, what I've noticed is that when I go and try to save the image from Firefox (version 15.0.1 on Snowleopard), the image itself cannot be opened. Saving the image from any other browser yields a working image that can be opened in any image editor.

What I find particularly interesting is WHEN it breaks. I'll see if I can explain this accurately.

The full working version is [**no longer here**], and here's all the relevant bits of code involved in the processing and generation of the Chart itself:

**chart.php** (process POST data)

```
$r = 300; //Radius
//Processing of information passed from the previous form yields an array $cargs
//$cargs contains key value pairs. Values are of type float with a range 0-$r

$chart = new Chart($r); //Generates Canvas and Circle
$chart->generate($cargs); //Generates Polygon based on $cargs

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagesavealpha($chart->image, true);
imagepng($chart->image);
imagedestroy($chart->image);
?>
```

**SS_Chart.php** (Chart Object)

```
class Chart
{
    public $radius;
    public $diameter;
    public $image;

    private $_labels;
    private $_values;
    private $_n;

    public function Chart($r=300)
    {
        $this->radius = $r;
        $this->diameter = 2*$r;
        $this->image = $this->_get_transparent_canvas($this->diameter, $this->diameter);
        $this->_draw_circle();
    }
    public function generate($arr)
    {
        if(count($arr)>2)
        {
            $red = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 0, 0);
            $this->_n = count($arr);
            $this->_labels = array_keys($arr);
            $this->_values = array_values($arr);

            $coors = array();
            for($i=0;$i<$this->_n;$i++)
            {
                //Generate coordinates....
            }
            imagefilledpolygon($this->image, $coors, $this->_n, $red);
        }
        else
            trigger_error('Number of $key=>$value pairs in arguments must be 3 or greater', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    private function _get_transparent_canvas($w, $h)
    {
        $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        imagealphablending($canvas, true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($canvas, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $transparent);

        return $canvas;
    }
    private function _draw_circle()
    {
        $white = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 255, 255);
        imagearc($this->image, $this->radius, $this->radius, $this->diameter, $this->diameter,  0, 360, $white);
    }
}
```

Here's where it gets interesting: When commenting out `$chart->generate($cargs);` in chart.php, Firefox will yield a working and editable Transparent png according to the dimensions, as well as a white circle.

However, if I comment out everything within `public function generate` in SS_Chart.php and leave `$chart->generate($cargs);` uncommented (basically resulting in a method that runs, but doesn't actually do anything), the resulting png can no longer be opened.

**How is that possible??**

I haven't found much on this issue apart from the odd forum here and there describing some difficulties in getting Firefox to jive with the GD Library, but this is the first time I've ever encountered anything like this.

- If it were a problem with my code, wouldn't the issue be prevalent across all browsers?
- Does this have more to do with Scoping, and the fact that the main GD functions are utilized within an Object?
- Moreover, does this issue happen for anybody else?
- Has anybody run into a problem like this before?
- Is this even a *known* problem?

This is actually more of a curiosity than it is a real "problem", but any insight into the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly do you get when you comment out the header? An empty page or a PNG content? What do you mean by it doesn't work in FF? Does it work in other browsers? I work a lot with GD and it should work on all browsers the same. It's backed after all. Could you also check /var/log/apache2/error.log to make sure there is no Seq Fault there.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, there is a link to the working version so you can test for yourself and see what I'm talking about. In Firefox, submit the form, save the image, and then try to load it in Photoshop or any kind of image editor. Then do the same in any other browser. There are no actual errors generated by the GD Library or PHP.

Comment: To clarify further for you, this is not a question in regards to an image "working" in a browser. The image displays just fine in any browser. It's the behavior I'm seeing after saving the image to a physical file that I'm curious about.

Comment: Sorry dude I didn't get your question straight away. It happens.

Comment: It's a pretty lengthy and unusual question, so no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the source of that **SAVED** image

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Number of $key=>$value pairs in arguments must be 3 or greater in <b>/home/mattmaio/public_html/dev/assets/classes/SS_Chart.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
```

When you save it in Firefox, fireox doesn't save what you see. What it does is - it makes an another  GET request on save.

```
GET http://dev.mattmaiorano.com/chart.php HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.mattmaiorano.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://dev.mattmaiorano.com/chart.php
```

Obviously all POST data is lost hence the error. I'm not sure about your commenting out thing but I guess that's what it is.

Comment: Now THAT is interesting. It hadn't occurred to me to open the file in a text editor. With this in mind, I'll continue to play around with the class file (maybe take the User Error out completely) and see if this can be remedied as-is, or perhaps storing the POST data in a Session for this kind of edge case. Either way, you've pointed me in the right direction. I'll leave this open for now, but I've upvoted your answer in the meantime to see if I can get more information.

Comment: The easiest thing would be to store POST in session so when the additional GET is performed you still have the correct image. Alternatively you can save it on disk and redirect after POST to that URL.

Comment: Also be careful with PHP close tags "?>". Don't use them if you don't have too. That might sneak some additional character (new line, empty space) into your images.

Comment: Another way would be to use GET, I suppose, even though it isn't the nicest method...

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 isses here

- Saving
- Broken Circle

#### Saving

What you should do is save the image and then use `readfile` to output it this way the files would not have to be regenerated  and also it works on Firefox

> Not having to generate the image all the time also helps to preserve bandwidth

Sample Code

```
$r = 300; // $cargs
$tempDir = "xxx";
session_start();

__flush($tempDir);

if (isset($_POST) || ! isset($_SESSION['file'])) {
    $_SESSION['file'] = $tempDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . sha1(serialize($_POST)) . ".png";
}

header("Content-type: image/png");
$file = $_SESSION['file'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
    readfile($file);
} else {
    $chart = new Chart($r); // Generates Canvas and Circle
    $chart->generate(array("A" => array(40,50),"B" => array(20,240),"C" => array(60,60),"D" => array(240,20),"E" => array(50,40),"F" => array(10,10))); // Generates

    imagesavealpha($chart->image, true);
    imagepng($chart->image, $file);
    imagedestroy($chart->image);
}
```

#### Broken Circle

The broken circle `has nothing to do with Firefox` .. In my initial investigation when i ran your code with my own variables it generated the following image ..

[image]

Issues

From the image above the `green` maker shows the broken circles. I got to find that this errors when the following is true:

> Canvas Width = Circle Diameter

Which form your code you are calling it like this:

```
imagearc($this->image, $this->radius, $this->radius, $this->diameter, $this->diameter, 0, 360, $white);
```

Solution

What you should do is reduce the diameter of the circle a little with something like this

```
  imagearc($this->image, $this->radius, $this->radius, ceil(0.9 * $this->diameter), ceil(0.9 * $this->diameter), 0, 360, $white);
```

And you would get a perfect circle

[image]

#### Code Used

```
$r = 300; // $cargs
$tempDir = "xxx";
session_start();

__flush($tempDir);

if (isset($_POST) || ! isset($_SESSION['file'])) {
    $_SESSION['file'] = $tempDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . sha1(serialize($_POST)) . ".png";
}

header("Content-type: image/png");
$file = $_SESSION['file'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
    readfile($file);
} else {
    $chart = new Chart($r); // Generates Canvas and Circle
    $chart->generate(array("A" => array(40,50),"B" => array(20,240),"C" => array(60,60),"D" => array(240,20),"E" => array(50,40),"F" => array(10,10))); // Generates

    imagesavealpha($chart->image, true);
    imagepng($chart->image, $file);
    imagedestroy($chart->image);
}

function __flush($tempDir) {
    $expire = 300; // 5mins
    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($tempDir);
    foreach ( $iterator as $fileinfo ) {

        if ($fileinfo->isDot())
            continue;

        if ((time() - $fileinfo->getMTime()) > $expire) {
            @unlink($iterator->getPath());
        }
    }
}


class Chart {
    public $radius;
    public $diameter;
    public $image;
    private $_labels;
    private $_values;
    private $_n;

    public function Chart($r = 300) {
        $this->radius = $r;
        $this->diameter = 2 * $r;
        $this->image = $this->_get_transparent_canvas($this->diameter, $this->diameter);
        $this->_draw_circle();
    }

    public function generate($arr) {
        if (count($arr) > 2) {
            $red = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 0, 0);
            $this->_n = count($arr);
            $this->_labels = array_keys($arr);
            $this->_values = array_values($arr);

            $coors = array();
            foreach ( $this->_values as $key => $value ) {
                $coors = array_merge($coors, $value);
            }
            imagefilledpolygon($this->image, $coors, $this->_n, $red);
        } else
            trigger_error('Number of $key=>$value pairs in arguments must be 3 or greater', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    private function _get_transparent_canvas($w, $h) {
        $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        imagealphablending($canvas, true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($canvas, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $transparent);

        return $canvas;
    }

    private function _draw_circle() {
        $white = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 255, 255);
        imagearc($this->image, $this->radius, $this->radius, ceil(0.9 * $this->diameter), ceil(0.9 * $this->diameter), 0, 360, $white);
        // imagearc($this->image, $this->radius, $this->radius,
    // $this->diameterCycle, $this->diameterCycle, 0, 360, $white);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had seen the broken circle, but wasn't too concerned about it at the time (rough draft, really). What I was planning on doing to fix it was provide a Padding parameter in the Constructor to increase the dimensions of the image itself, and center the circle within the result. However, your proposed solution to circumvent the second GET request upon save using readfile is one I had not considered. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for a thorough answer.